# how to add hitTestObject statement inside a timer class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, hittest

Apologise if this is a very obvious question.

I'm wanting to add a hitTestObject if loop to a mini game.
The obstacles are 3 items within an array, all 3 are movie clips that play individually in succession with a timer class delay of 1 second.
However due to the loops (I'm assuming) the hitTestObject if statement is not returning the trace 'hit' nor any errors - how should I resolve this?

Thank you in advance!

```
function randomSort(a:*, b:*):Number
{
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) return -1;
    else return 1;
}
var obstacleArray:Array = [obstacleCar,obstacleCar2,obstacleCar3];
obstacleArray.sort(randomSort);

//(no need for the shuffledLetters[] Array)
trace(obstacleArray);
trace(obstacleArray.length);


//OBSTACLE START DELAY
var timerPlay:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
timerPlay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, ontimerPlay);
timerPlay.start();
var i:int = 0;
var timerDelay:Timer = new Timer(1000, 3);
function ontimerPlay(evt:TimerEvent):void{
    if (carTarget.hitTestObject(obstacleArray[i]) == true){
    trace("HIT!");
    }
    //FOR EACH OBSTACLE

    timerDelay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, ontimerDelay);
    timerDelay.start();

}
function ontimerDelay(evt:TimerEvent):void{
    obstacleArray[i].play();
    trace(i);
    i++;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are performing a hit test once, before any of the obstacle movie clips have played. You probably want to perform the hit test repeatedly, every frame.

Add this to **onTimerDelay()** :

```
if(i === 0) {
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameListener)
}
```

And then create the listener function outside of ontimerDelay(), 
and put your hit test there :

```
function enterFrameListener(evt:Event):void {
    var index:int = Math.max(0, i - 1);
    if (carTarget.hitTestObject(obstacleArray[index]) == true){
        trace("HIT!");
    }
}
```

This will perform the hit test once every frame between carTarget and the currently playing obstacle.

A note on your vocabulary:

1. There aren't any loops in your code. An "if" statement is not a
   loop, it is known as a "conditional statement".
2. ontimerDelay() will be called 3 times, but it isn't really a loop, 
   even though it is  called repeatedly.
3. In your code, you are not adding a hit test to a timer class. 
   A class is sortof a blueprint that is used to make class instances 
   (timerPlay and timerDelay). You are adding a hit test to an "event listener"
   registered with an "instance" of the timer class.

**Edit**

Regarding the errors you mentioned in your comment, my previous example was wrong. I was referring to the currently playing movie clip with the index i, but it should really be i - 1. Each time you play a new obstacle movie clip, you increment i, so i is no longer the index of the currently playing movie clip. The only time you don't need to subtract 1 is when i is 0. I updated my previous example.

I also moved the event listener registration into onTimerDelay and wrapped it in a if statement, so that hit tests are not performed until the first movie clip starts playing.

**Edit**

If you only want the trace "Hit"  when contact between the two objects begins, you will need to keep track of the result of the last hit test. In the enterFrameListener, you can then check to see if there was a hit in the last frame. If there wasn't a hit in the last frame and there is a hit in the current frame, you can trace "Hit". If there was a hit in the last frame and a hit in the current frame, you can skip your trace statement.

```
var lastHitTestResult:Boolean = false;

function enterFrameListener(evt:Event):void {
    var index:int = Math.max(0, i - 1);
    var currentHitTestResult:Boolean = carTarget.hitTestObject(obstacleArray[index])
    if(lastHitTestResult === false && currentHitTestResult === true) {
        trace("HIT!")
    }
    lastHitTestResult = currentHitTestResult
}
```

Just make sure to reset lastHitTestResult to false in onTimerDelay

Comment: Thank you for your help, that's cleared up a lot of understanding.
I've followed your advice but incurred a problem when running.  
  
Firstly a Migration Warning 1090  
  
Secondly when running. After Mc's have finished.  
    TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
 at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
 at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
 at tsunamigetawayV_fla::MainTimeline/onEnterFrame()[tsunamigetawayV_fla.MainTimeline::frame83:83]    
  
Line 83: refers to  
    if (carTarget.hitTestObject(obstacleArray[i]) == true){

Comment: @user2075625 I added another code example that will hopefully clear up the errors. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Cheers for getting back! I'm afraid it's still not functioning correctly. - It still displays the migrating warning, and the 2007 error is still appearing.  
I've found however that by adding an if statement  
if (i < 2){ i++; }. Hits do appear but seemingly at random, (even when just one collision is made - more than one hit appears. in a row after all 3 items have played) Thanks again.

Comment: @user2075625 I think the migration warning is happening because I named the event Listener onEnterFrame, and there is a built in function called onEnterFrame in Actionscript 2.0. I updated the code examples so that the listener has a different name.

Comment: I think the problem is the fact I haven't mentioned that each of the 3 array items has it's own unique classic tween. You're method does work but only when hittesting a specific MC e.g. objectCar, it now means however that it traces hit with each refresh as the MC travels over the target.  
Very sorry for any confusion!

Comment: @user2075625 Please see my two edits in the answer. Hopefully they will help!

Answer (score 0):

The first timer that you have created lasts for one second only. This means that you are effectively checking for collisions only once and that too before your obstacles start playing. 
So, when your obstacles are playing, the first timer handler is not being called. You can trace to verify this.